# how to predict related videos to a video in weka

Tags: weka, predict, related-content

I'm trying to predict related videos to a video,
is that possible in weka?
the database takes the following structrue:

```
    video_id,catygory,keywords,related_videos_ids
```

a single keywords field might have many values (for ex: stackoverflow, predict, videos),so the related_videos (the video could have more than one related video).
The related videos depend on catygory an keywords
what's the way to do that in weka?? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it in weka. You should look into clustering:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjYUYJ2b4r8

I would also suggest trying to get more features (more columns) for better results.

Comment: Well.. you've just earned my 50 reputations and my respect *_^
one more thing, only Hierarchical Clusterer is activated, and when I'm using it it doesn't show all the results for large number of clusters (above 12 clusters)
do you know how to show all the clusters?